# Postgres, groupBy and count for table and relations at the same time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called 'users' that has the following structure:

| id (PK) | campaign_id | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |
| 2 | 1234 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |
| 3 | 123 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |
| 4 | 123 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |

At the same time I have a table that tracks clicks per user:

| id (PK) | user_id(FK) | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-07-14T10:30:01.967Z |

Both of these table are up to millions of records... I need the most efficient query to group the data per `campaign_id`.
The result I am looking for would look like this:

| campaign_id | total_users | total_clicks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 | 1 |
| 1234 | 1 | 3 |

I unfortunately have no idea how to achieve this while minding performance and most important of it all I need to use `WHERE` or `HAVING` to limit the query in a certain time range by `createdAt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, `PostgreSQL` is not my forte, nor is `SQL`. But, I'm learning spending some time on your question. Have a go with `INNER JOIN` after two seperate `SELECT()` statements:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT campaign_id, COUNT (t1."id(PK)") total_users FROM t1 GROUP BY campaign_id
  ) tbl1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT campaign_id, COUNT (t2."user_id(FK)") total_clicks FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1."id(PK)" = t2."user_id(FK)" GROUP BY campaign_id
  ) tbl2
  USING(campaign_id)
```

See an online [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/05247/4/0). I believe this is now also ready for a `WHERE` clause in both `SELECT` statements to filter by "createdAt". I'm pretty sure someone else will come up with something better.

Good luck.

Comment: I think `INNER JOIN` between `tbl1` and `tbl2` should be `LEFT JOIN`, because it is possible for a campaign to exist and have some users, but not have any clicks yet. In this case we should return a row for this `campaign_id` with user count and zero clicks. With `INNER JOIN` such row would not be returned.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, that's great advise. I'll puzzle on that a bit later (will have to read about it).

Comment: This solution worked great with using `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
select u.campaign_id,
       count(distinct u.id) users_count,
       count(c.user_id) clicks_count 
from 
       users u left join clicks c on u.id=c.user_id
group by 1;
```

[See here query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTMvZ.png)